# Як перекласти з російської спонукальне "давай"/"давайте"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian, росіянізм, розмовна-українська, наказовий-спосіб

Я звик використовувати спонукальне "**давайте**"/ "**давай**" у російськомовному побуті.

> - **Давай** (зробімо) ревью.
> - **Давай** глянеш код
> - **Давай** спробуємо  ось так, а якщо не спрацює ...
> - **Давайте** не будемо (переходити на особистості)
> - **Давайте** працювати [*т.т. припиняємо галасувати і починаємо працювати*]

Але є одне але - слів "**давайте**"/ "**давай**" немає в українській мові.

До гурту можна звернутися "[нумо](http://sum.in.ua/s/numo)"

> НУМО 1, виг. Уживається при звертанні до багатьох осіб як спонукання,
> заохочення до спільної дії. — Та годі вам клопотатись! Нумо
> вечеряти!.. (Марко Вовчок, I, 1955, 205);

Воно, як на мене, складає враження занадто емоційного і пафосного заклику. Згадується відоме: " Нумо, браття!". Мені хочеться чогось буденного.

Є ще "[гайда](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghajda)"

> ГА́ЙДА, виг., у знач. присудк. сл., розм. Уживається як заклик,
> спонукання іти куди-небудь: ідіть, ходім. — Гайда, діти! погасав
> Каганець козачий! (Тарас Шевченко, I, 1951, 130);

Цей заклик можна використати до однієї людини, але фокус лише на фізичному переміщенні. І та сама проблема більшої емоційності ніж хочеться.

Власне моє питання - які найближчі еквіваленти є в українській мові?

Comment: Гадаю, що українській властиво одразу вживати спонукальні дієслова без допоміжних слів (_поглянь_ пис, _спробуймо_ ось так тощо) і се є буденним. Тому буде дещо проблемніше вишукувати тотожність.

Comment: @Follower Мені теж так здається. Ще існує частка «но» (перше значення у [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/no)).

Comment: Можете описати детальніше, чому ви вирішили, що "Але є одне але - слів "давайте"/ "давай" немає в українській мові."? Я, наприклад, знайшов це слово в українському словнику. Якщо такого слова не існує в українській мові, то як тоді перекласти це слово українською в прикладі: "Давайте йому 3 пігулки щодня?".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

На відміну від російської мови, українська має окрему форму дієслова для наказового способу першої особи множини. Її треба використовувати замість рос. "давайте":

> - **Зробімо** рев'ю.
> - **Поглянь** на код (наказовий спосіб 2 особа, однина. Тут і в російській, як на мене, "давай" зайве, можна просто рос. "Посмотри код")
> - **Спробуймо** ось так, а якщо не спрацює ...
> - Не **переходьмо** на особистості
> - **Працюймо** (хоча трохи природніше буде з "годі теревенити/байдикувати" поряд)

Якщо не впевнені, як утворити цю форму, скористайтеся, наприклад, сайтом http://slovnyk.ua

Докладніша стаття: http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/165.htm

Щодо "нумо": не сказав би, що воно пафосне, але так, значно емоційніше за рос. "давайте".

Comment: Цікава дрібничка пов'язана з [відмінюванням](http://slovnyk.ua/?swrd=%C7%D0%CE%C1%B3%CC%CE&x=0&y=0). - Ми зроб**И**мо це завтра. - Зроб**І**мо зараз, чого чекати ?!.

Answer (score 6):

Є спонукальне "давай-но", навіть у правописі згадується:

> § 33.Частки
>   ...
>   3. Через дефіс пишуться:
>   а) Частки бо, но, от, то, таки, коли вони виділяють значення окремого слова: іди́-бо; **дава́й-но**; ті́льки-но; так-о́т, як-о́т; отаки́й-то, сті́льки-то, ти́м-то, я́кось-то; важки́й-таки, все́-таки, діста́в-таки, та́к-таки.

Приклад використання - вірш [Ігоря Павлюка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BA_%D0%86%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%97%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) "[Давай-но море](https://www.ukrlib.com.ua/books/printit.php?tid=13396), вийдем з берегів...":

> **Давай-но**, море, вийдем з берегів
>   До всіх отих людських страждань і болів.
>   Із піни ти народжуєш богів,
>   Солониш пілігримам прісність волі.
>   <...>

Answer (score 5):

Як спонукальну частку можна використовувати [лишень](http://sum.in.ua/s/lyshenj), але при цьому все одно потрібно вживати наказовий спосіб

Наприклад:

> **Подай, лишень**, дочко, свитку, я трохи полежу (Степан Васильченко, III, 1960, 77)

> Так ну, **лишень, понюхаймо** кабаки (Кв.-Осн., II, 1956, 112).

> **Згадаймо лишень** про депортацію вчених з Києво-Могилянської академії до Санкт-Петербурга за вказівкою Петра І. (з газ.)

Comment: Цікава думка. Не бажаєте розгорнути відповідь, додавши приклади вжитку?

Comment: @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine Додав приклади вживання з деяких словників. Дякую Вам за пораду.

Answer (score 4):

Якихось відчутних проблем з наказовим способом дієслова московська мова не має, просто форма першої особа множини імперативу там ідентична з формою індикативу (як і в низці інших мов). Дієслівна форма давай(те) в обговорюваній функції віддавна (принаймні від 19-го ст.) присутня в українському мовленні. Що її потрібно звідти усувати — це ще слід довести. Те, що вона є можливим московським запозиченням (що знову ж таки наразі не доведено), само по собі ще нічого не означає.

Answer (score 3):

[Відповідь](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2859/) пана Kyrylo Yatsenko вже пропонує декілька варіантів питомих українських слів, які можна використовувати замість *«давайте»* у спонукальному контексті.

Письменник Тарас Прохасько наполегливо радить уникати прямого калькування слова *«давайте»* у цьому контексті і натомість **використовувати слова, що позначають пряме прохання**, як-то *«прошу»*.
Автор аргументує це тим, що москв. *«давайте»* містить одноосібну вимогу з боку однієї особи, яка завуальована під «спільне рішення» чи «спільну дію». Автор вважає це типовим для авторитарних суспільств, але неприйнятним для українського суспільства.

---

Розправа [«Давай, прошу»](https://zbruc.eu/node/92560) пана [Тараса Прохаська](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

> …
>
> Мене тоді вразило одне слово. Давай! Навіщо перед розказуй треба поставити цей імператив? Так я почав на практиці вивчати сутність того, що закладене у російській мові.
>
> *Давай покуримо* – так говорили, підсівши до когось з сигаретою, даючи зрозуміти, що частину сигарети треба віддати. *Давай ділитися* – і хтось, хто почав їсти булку, отримував інформацію, що ділитися доведеться тільки йому.
>
> *Давай роздягайся* – казали вони своїм шмарам. Давай підемо – і ти розумієш, що це пропозиція, від якої неможливо відмовитися. *Давай помовчимо* – якщо після цього щось скажеш, то виявишся хамом, який порушив домовленість.
>
> У цьому російському “давай” ховається вся природа природної російської експансії. Її вагомість полягає в односторонній примсі, яка стала рішенням, що переростає у вимогу. Але має таку куревську дипломатичну зачіпку, що виглядає на спільне бажання, успішне виконання якого перетворюється у спільну справу. Йому захотілося, а ти зобов'язаний, бо це ж ми, ми разом і це наш уже інтерес. Як ти можеш не хотіти такого, що я запропонував. Давай! Російське “давай” є майстерним переносом.
>
> Коли вони кажуть “давай”, то йдеться передовсім про віддавання. Бензин ваш, ідеї наші. Я все організую, а ти подбай про реалізацію.
>
> Російське “давай” скероване насамперед на віддавання власної волі. Пропозиція “давай” – якою би вона не була – означає тільки одне: зроби для мене то, що я хочу, повіривши, що так буде найкраще тобі. Ти думав, що можеш бути для себе? Ні, давай будемо щось робити разом.
>
> За кожну відмову від “давай” тебе чекає жорстока дидактична покара, бо не можна дбати лиш про себе.
>
> Українське “дай” зовсім не з того регістру. Дай не передбачає злиття. Навіть тоді, коли *дай ми, мила, дай ми, щос ми обіцяла*.
>
> Там, де в російській мирне “давай” наповнене тиском і безальтернативністю (навіть у дитячих віршиках – *ану малиш давай скорєє отгадай*), в українському аналогові звучить запрошення, прошу, апеляція до отримання дозволу і готовність почути відмову, вільному воля.
>
> *Давайтє жить дружно, давай вєчєром з тобой встрєтімся, давайтє понімать друг друга с полуслова*… Зловіщі формули, що несуть в собі вимогу ентузіастичного упокорення.
>
> Давай, давай – це фраза незабутнього жаху, яка увійшла без перекладу у мови всіх перейдених росіянами народів. Підозріваю, що навіть мафіозі усіх країн мусять зважати на таку протокольну деталь у переговорах зі своїми російськими колегами.
>
> Звичайно, що у житті кожної людини може статися безвихідна ситуація, коли рускій скаже – дай, і мусиш то віддати, щоби він тебе не вбив і забрав то, що хотів. Але щоби залишитися собою, хоч би й мертвим, до останньої риски не можна приставати на миле “а давай”. Ліпше через **прошу**, яке вони так ненавидять, бо це передбачає інший ступінь вільності.

Comment: Здається, що це чийсь емоційний коментар, а не відповідь на запитання «як перекласти…?»

Comment: @bytebuster розширив розправу, котра справді почутӧва, але таке передусӥм, аби показати ріжницю і суть слова давај. Є прямиј переклад слова до давај. Московська справді має проблеми з наказовим способом дїӧслова, але вона ӧго таки має на розмовномі рівнї, тут шчось инше.

Comment: А можна коротко резюме/висновки?

Comment: Upd.: Прочитав до кінця. По-моєму, це суто художній твір (що намагається передати власне бачення/емоції автора), але аж ніяк не мовознавча рекомендація (що мала б або спиратися лише на загальновизнані значення слів, або робити власні висновки щодо семантики слів лише на основі статистичної вибірки достатнього розміру).

Comment: Маю на меті одну думку, спробуу здїјснити ввечері чи ві вихідних.

Comment: @stegetsj, я додав summary своїми словами, у тій мірі, як я зрозумів автора розлогої цитати. Якщо щось неправильно, feel free to edit.

Comment: Так а якже використовувати слово *прошу* замість *давайте*? *Прошу жити дружно*, *прошу зустрітись ввечері*?

Answer (score 2):

Ваше запитання має особисту думку, тому і в моїй відповіді вона буде.

До ваших прикладів можна дібрати такі найближчі еквіваленти:

- Зробімо ревью
- А глянь-но код
- Спробуймо ось так, а якщо не спрацює ...
- Нумо не переходити на особистості *або* Нумо без особистостей
- Годі галасувати і нумо працювати *або* Не галасуймо, а працюймо

### Пояснення і висновок

- Наказовий спосіб першої особи множини — найменш забарвлений спосіб заохоти та пропозиції
- [Нумо](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE) — заклик до спільної дії; емоційніший
- [Годі](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%96) — заклик припинити дію; емоційніший
- [А](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%90) — заклик чи наказ виконувати дію на початку речень біля присудків. Особисто я сприймаю його ще як пропозицію.

Інше:
Ну ж бо — підсилення заохоти, як-от у «[Ну ж бо, тримаймо стрій!](https://www.pisni.org.ua/songs/9471982.html)» замість схожого «[Давай, вставай](https://www.smule.com/song/%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9-karaoke-lyrics/4523704_4523704/arrangement)». У СУМ-і прямо означення не дано, але його можна посередньо скласти. [Ну](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%9D%D1%83) [Ж](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B6%D0%B5) [Бо](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B1%D0%BE)