# Як замінити "давай" у фразах на зразок "давай підійду ближче"?

Tags: вживання-слів, дієслова, словосполучення, наказовий-спосіб

Раніше вже було [питання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2858/) про давай/давайте у фразах на кшталт «давай співати». Тут давай можна замінити також на нумо, буде «нумо співати». А можна використовувати наказовий спосіб: «співаймо».

Але є трішки інші фрази — той, хто говорить фразу, може пропонувати, щоб деяку річ зробив він, або третя особа, або група людей, яка включає його, але не того, кому адресовано фразу. Також може бути наголошено слово ми.

Наприклад:

1. Давай підійду ближче
2. Давай я піду перша
3. Давай я приїду о 12:30
4. Давай ми це зробимо
5. Давай ти спочатку спробуєш сам
6. Давай вони нам напишуть

Уточнення для прикладу «давай ми це зробимо». Тут ми може як включати, так і не включати того, кому адресовано фразу. І тут може підкреслюватися якраз слово ми: тобто той, хто говорить фразу, наголошує на тому, щоб не інша, а саме ця група людей зробила те, про що він каже.

Які ще існують варіанти сказати те саме? І чи притаманно українській мові таке застосування слів давай і давайте?

Для 5 прикладу такий варіант виглядає дуже схожим: спробуй-но спочатку сам. Для 6 є ще такий варіант: нехай вони нам напишуть.

Для 1–4 є близькі варіанти з дозволь або дай, але відтінок виходить зовсім інший. Порівняйте: «давай я піду перша», «дозволь мені піти першою» й «дай я піду перша». У всіх 3 випадках значення близьке, але відтінки значно відрізняються.

Якщо хтось має інші варіанти або зауваження щодо цих, було би дуже цікаво дізнатися.

Answer (score 4):

Здається, усі запропоновані вами варіанти зводяться до тих, що обговорені у пов'язаній відповіді, якщо додати (відтворити) пропущену частину фрази:

- *«давай **домовимося, що** я піду перша»*
- *«давай **узгодимо, що** ти спочатку спробуєш сам»*
- *«давай **дочекаємося, поки** вони нам напишуть»*

Іншими словами, це такий само м'який імператив, просто пропущено дієслово.

Підтвердженням цього може слугувати спостереження, що після *давай* йде повноцінне речення (clause) з підметом і присудком, і, як наслідок, тут «проситься»¹ кома, як це зазвичай робиться при правописі складнопідрядних речень.
На відміну від словосполучень з дієсловом у невизначеній формі (інфінітив) (*давай ділитися*), де кома не ставиться. Або навіть якщо дієслово має іншу форму (*давай спробуємо*).

---

¹) На мою суб'єктивну думку. Я не знайшов джерел, які підтверджували б це.

Comment: Тобто треба казати: *домовмося я піду перша*, *узгодьмо ти спочатку спробуєш сам* і *дочекаймося вони нам напишуть*?

Comment: @meleten ні, у відповіді не йдеться про те, що пропущене дієслово могло б замінити слово "давай".

Comment: А могли би будь ласка дати українські варіанти, щоби сказати те саме, як попросив автор?

Comment: @meleten я зрозумів ваше уточнення. Я бачу ситуацію так: автор запитання висловив сумнів у тому, що лексичне значення слова «давай» (2-а особа) не відповідає контексту (як-то «давай» + дієслово, що стосується 1-ї особи «я/ми» або 3-ї особи «він/вона/вони»). Я намагався спростувати такий сумнів. Іншими словами, моя відповідь — *замінювати не треба*, лексика і контекст не суперечать одне одному, бо «давай» і дієслова знаходяться *у різних* частинах складно-підрядного речення.

Comment: @meleten Менше з тим, я згоден, що моя відповідь не наводить авторитетних джерел; спробую принагідно такі джерела навести, дякую за підказку.

Comment: Мені здається автор спитав про *давай* як росіянізм, аніж невідповідність осіб.

Answer (score 1):

Нумо або гайда !

До гурту можна звернутися «нумо»

НУМО 1, виг. Уживається при звертанні до багатьох осіб як спонукання, заохочення до спільної дії. — Та годі вам клопотатись! Нумо вечеряти!.. (Мар
ко Вовчок, I, 1955, 205);

Є ще "гайда"
ГА́ЙДА, виг., у знач. присудк. сл., розм. Уживається як заклик, спонукання іти куди-небудь: ідіть, ходім. — Гайда, діти! погасав Каганець козачий! (Та
рас Шевченко, I, 1951, 130);

Answer (score 1):

До ваших прикладів

1. Давай підійду ближче
2. Давай я піду перша
3. Давай я приїду о 12:30
4. Давай ми це зробимо
5. Давай ти спочатку спробуєш сам
6. Давай вони нам напишуть

можна дібрати такі аналоги:

1. Нехай [я] підійду ближче
2. Нехай я піду перша
3. Нехай я приїду о 12:30
4. А зробімо ми це
5. Спробуй ти сам спочатку
6. Нехай вони нам напишуть

### Пояснення

Для [наказу третім особам](https://www.miyklas.com.ua/p/ukrainska-mova/11-klas/morfologichna-norma-379685/diyeslovo-diyeslivni-formi-diyevidmini-diyesliv-nakazovii-sposib-380008/re-1dd896a4-7715-400c-825e-20ef243931a0) можна вжити *нехай*; хоч це неможливо до себе, тут думаю теж можна вжити нехай, оскільки в російській теж такого немає, і вони тулять *давай*.
Якщо ви хочете наказати особам, де спосіб можливий, з наголошенням, то ви спокійно можете це зробити, можливо додавши частку [*а*](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B0).

### Висновок

У ваших випадках *давай* можна замінити на *нехай* та наказовий спосіб з уточненням виконавця.